# ga tracking event not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to track a link click using Google Analytics. I have already loaded site data to Google Analytics, but can't get event tracking to work. The events I am trying to track are clicks on phone number and email links. From a Google page on [Outbound Link Tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en), I copied down this code:

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
```

and modified the element I want to track:

```
Tech Tutors 4 Seniors  
<a href="mailto:techtutors4seniors@gmail.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('mailto:techtutors4seniors@gmail.com');return false;" style="float:right;color:white; margin-right:10px">email</a>
<a href="tel:222-393-8839" style="float:right; color:white;margin-right:20px;">222-393-8839 | </a>
```

Please let me know what the problem may be.

Comment: How are you determining that it's not working? I copy and pasted the same code to my site and it seems fine. You have set the transport beacon so the hit will show up as a POST rather than a GET. Other than that, I can see the `mailto` click event in GA Debugger.

Comment: When I click the email link I don't see the event show up in Google Analytics>Real Time>Events .

Comment: Do you have any filter set up to exclude your hits? Also check with GA Debugger. I'm able to see the RT hit.

Comment: not that i know of. I checked with GA Debugger and nothing showed up on my console, not even "Initializing Google Analytics"

Comment: I noticed i was missing these lines from my code: `ga('create','UA-84331443-1','auto');
ga('send','pageview');` Will try again

Comment: Yep, that would do it. ;) The code is fine though as I see it.

Comment: Thanks, do i need to use  `ga('send', 'event', 'contact', 'headercontact', 'email or phone');` instead because I'm only interested in clicks?

Comment: aahh... i had ghostery turned on. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So everything good now?

Comment: Yes, I fixed the problem.